# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{(x-2)\sqrt{x^{2}-4x+3}}\, dx$ by completing the square and doing trigonometric substitution

Tags: integration, trigonometry

My problem is:
$$\int \frac{1}{(x-2)\sqrt{x^{2}-4x+3}}\, dx$$

Complete the square,
$$\int \frac{1}{(x-2)\sqrt{(x-2)^{2}-1}}\, dx$$

I know I'm probably supposed to use
$ \frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{arcsec}(u) = \frac{1}{|u|\sqrt{(u^2 - 1)}} * \frac{du}{dx}$
for the trig substitution

but what would that give me?
Any help would be useful. I don't remember trig super well.

Comment: Set $x-2=u$ and hence $dx=du$. Then apply the result you already know.

Comment: So is it just arcsec(x-2)+C?

Comment: Substitute $t= \sqrt{x^{2}-4x+3} $
$$\int \frac{1}{(x-2)\sqrt{x^{2}-4x+3}}\, dx
=\int \frac1{1+t^2}dt =\tan^{-1}t
$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the trigonometric substitution $x=\sec{u}+2$. Then $dx=\sec{u}\tan{u}du$. Hence the integral becomes
$$\int\frac{\sec{u}\tan{u}}{\sec{u}\tan{u}}du=u+c=\arccos{\left(\frac{1}{x-2}\right)}+c$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:

$$x-2=\cosh t$$

Then:

$$\sqrt{(x-2)^2-1}=\sinh t, \ \ \ dx=\sinh t dt$$

From which

$$\int \frac{1}{(x-2)\sqrt{(x-2)^{2}-1}} dx=\int \frac{1}{\cosh t \sinh t} \sinh t dt=\int \frac{1}{\cosh t} dt$$